# onActivityResult not doing anything

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create an image chooser wherein the user will pick an image, and an `ImageView` will be appended to a `linear layout` with the image selected as its image resource. Here is my code, I don't know what's wrong but no `ImageView` is appended to the LinearLayout

```
private void pickImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        return;
    } else if(resultCode == 1) {
        final Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            //IMAGE SELECTED
            Bitmap imageSelected = extras.getParcelable("data");

            final View listingImage = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.image_listing, null);
            Button remove = (Button)listingImage.findViewById(R.id.removeImage);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)listingImage.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            //SET IMAGE OF IMAGEVIEW TO SELECTED IMAGE
            imageView.setImageBitmap(imageSelected);

            remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    linearLayout.removeView(listingImage);
                }
            });
            //ADD IMAGEVIEW TO LINEARLAYOUT
            linearLayout.addView(listingImage, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

`pickImage()` is called from a button.

Comment: `else if(resultCode == 1)` – Presumably, you meant to check `requestCode` there, not `resultCode`.

Comment: Change `else if(resultCode == 1)` to `else if(requestCode== 1)`

Comment: Same. Nothing happens

Comment: I know now the reason but I know not why. final `Bundle extras = data.getExtras();` is null, why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Prince Mikael, you are not able to go to onActivityResult because you wrote the condition wrong. It will be the request code, not the result code hence you are unable to save the selected image.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            Uri contentURI = data.getData();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), contentURI);
                String path = saveImage(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                listing_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, baos);
                byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();
                String temp= Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
}
```

Now you can append the image to the linear layout.